# android form field hiding by virtual keyboard stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan is not working

Tags: android, forms

i have a form which contains 12 textview and editText. when i want to input some data in the last editText of screen, virtual keyboard is hidding it. I tried the following but it didnt work.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

any suggestion on this?

In some devices like HTC Hero it is working fine. while in another devices like samsung , motorola, xperia this problem is arrising.

Comment: Just use stateVisible|adjustPan

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to put everything in a scrollview
2. use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Comment: I have header footer and in middle this form. my form is already is in scroll view,